# Problems with "Makemigrations" in django

Tags: python, makemigrations

I'm trying to run "python manage.py makemigrations" but appears "No changes detected" . I had done changes so I don't know where is the problem. HELP!

Comment: can you try `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` and see if still no change is detected?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you run makemigrations on the original data schema, before you changed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need a check the directory where is the files .pyc and delete all files
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to save model file

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to specify the app for which you made the changes. And don't forget to save.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app-name
python manage.py migrate
```